# Need a good explanation on how Vagrant Share works

Tags: url, vagrant, share, private-network

I'm using Vagrant 1.7+ and had a working success on getting it to work with my settings.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.00+ and the problem I'm facing is that I can't share my project to outside source.

I'm currently having on "private_network" and what I can understand is that its a inside only network but everything works, hosts work and I can access my project via domain.

Then I tried the "public_network" but then nothing works, the plugin that makes the hosts for me won't work and I can't seem to share my url also.

By share I mean the "vagrant share" function.

Someone out there who can show me/tell me how to fix so my team can (outside the office) can see how far I have come so they can review my work?

## My Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Starting up Setup.sh"
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8885, auto_correct: true
config.hostsupdater.remove_on_suspend = true
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: '172.16.35.51', :netmask => '255.255.0.0', :bridge => 'eth0'
config.vm.hostname = File.basename(Dir.getwd)+ ".dev"
#config.hostsupdater.aliases = ["alias.testing.de", "alias2.somedomain.com"]

# Name will dynamic fetch the name of the project #
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
     end
     config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.path = "setup.sh"
     end
   config.vm.post_up_message = "Machine ready, use `vagrant ssh` to connect to it."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem!
You don't need public_network, its just that if you haven't customise the custom domain in Vagrant Share then you need to do something with the DNS.. otherwise if you don't have a custom domain.. it will work automatic